# Strong parameters for nested attributes with nested attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, strong-parameters

I have a "Recipe" which has_many "Ilists" and the "Ilist" has_one "ingredient", I'm trying to submit everything in one form but I'm having a problem with strong parameters. I can submit the form but looking at the console I can see in the POST request:

```
"Unpermitted parameter: ingredient_attributes"
```

recipes_controller.rb

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_recipe, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
  @recipes = Recipe.all
end
def create
  @recipe = Recipe.new
  6.times { @recipe.ilists.build }
end
. 
.
private
  def recipe_params
    params.require(:recipe).permit(:title, :photo, ... , :description, :calories, ilists_attributes: [ :ingredient_attributes, :quantity])
  end
end
```

I tried writing it like this but it doesnt work:

```
, ilists_attributes: [ ingredient_attributes: [ name, calories, ... ], :quantity])
```

Please help this is killing me!

this is the form i am submitting with

```
 <%= f.fields_for :ilists do |builder| %>
  <tr>

  <%= builder.fields_for :ingredient, Ingredient.new do |b| %>
    <td><%= b.collection_select(:_id, Ingredient.all, :id, :name) %></td>
  <% end %>

  <td><%= builder.text_field :quantity %></td>

  </tr>
```

Comment: What do your POST parameters look like, and what html is generated for the ingredient select tag? Do they match as expected?

Answer (score 1):

You're close.  Just a couple of rules to follow here.

Here are the correct strong params declaration

```
def recipe_params
  params.require(:recipe).permit(:name , ilists_attributes:  [ :quantity, ingredients_attributes: [ :name, :calories ]])
end
```

1. Make sure you pluralize plural objects (in your case it should be ingredients_attributes not ingredient)
2. make sure you put individual attributes BEFORE a nested array of attributes (in your case move quanity to the front of the list before ingredients_attributes)
3. Make sure there is a color : after attributes

Comment: is in not 'ingredient_attributes' for the 'has_one' association?

Comment: it is, indeed.  Wasn't saying that part was wrong, just that you have to be aware of the pluralization :)

Comment: I'm fairly new to rails and i have learned this the hard way :P

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution somewhere else all I had to do was swap the ingredient attributes to the other side.

```
, ilists_attributes: [ :quantity, ingredient_attributes: [ name, calories, ... ] ])
```